# case-insensitive matching in xpath on VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, case-insensitive

I am trying to get the attribute of a single node in VBA,  but can't manage it using DOM when i want it to be **case-insensitive**

VBA:

```
Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Dim el As Object
Dim XML As String

XML =("C:\........")

oDoc.validateOnParse = True
oDoc.Load XML  


dim Name as String
Name= "yaron"


  'select the User node with Name="Yaron"
    Set el = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GetUserInfo/User[@Name='" & Name & "']")
   'Set el = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GetUserInfo/User[matches(@Name, 'Name ' ,'i')]")    
   'Set el = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GetUserInfo/User[lower-case(@Name)='" & Name & "']")


    If Not el Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print el.getAttribute("LoginName")
Else
    Debug.Print "user id not found!"
End If
```

XML:

```
  <GetUserInfo>
           <User ID="16" Name="DAVID" LoginName="login1"/>
           <User ID="17" Name="GAL" LoginName="login2"/>
           <User ID="18" Name="YARON" LoginName="login3"/>
  </GetUserInfo>
```

2 lines in comment two different ways i tried after sow solutions in this site, 
but apparently those solution won't work for **VBA-**Excel****
i get run-time error '-2147467259(80004005); 'unknown method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `XPATH 2.0` functions are not possible because `MSXML` does not support XPath 2.0 `*grr*` the only possibility to be case insensitive with comparing attribute contents will be using [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate) function.

```
    Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
...
    Set el = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GetUserInfo/User[translate(@Name, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')='" & UCase(sName) & "']")
```

This needs at least `Microsoft XML, v4.0`, better `Microsoft XML, v6.0`.
The `Microsoft XML, v3.0` (`MSXML2.DOMDocument30`) will not suit.

If attribute values are uppercase always then

```
Set el = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GetUserInfo/User[@Name='" & UCase(sName) & "']")
```

will also fit.

Comment: unfortunately I get same error. maybe  translate function can't work with XPath 2.0  as well, :(

Comment: and i can't use the other option because Xml can be sometimes LOWER and sometime UPPER case

Comment: This needs at least `Microsoft XML, v4.0`, better `Microsoft XML, v6.0`.
The `Microsoft XML, v3.0` (`MSXML2.DOMDocument30`) will not suit.

Comment: ok i found my problem i used MSXML2.DOMDocument30  instated MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to match it using the lower-case function as you have tried, however the names of the attributes ARE case sensitive, so you need @Name not @name.

```
Set el = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GetUserInfo/User[lower-case(@Name)='" & Name & "']")
```

Comment: i get run-time error '-2147467259(80004005);
'unknown method

Comment: maybe i need to add a references?